# confused at double recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to understand how the output of the following code results in : cbaccbacbac by calling Mys(7) in main.

```
public static void Mys(int n){
        if(n == 0){
            System.out.println("a");

        }
        else if(n == 1 ){
            System.out.println("b");

        }
        else if(n == 3){
            System.out.println("c");
        }

        else{
            Mys(n-1);
            Mys(n-2);
        }
    }
```

Could someone please explain how the entire flow of recursion works here. I am a bit confused.

Thanks

Comment: TAKE IT TO THE PAPER  & PENCIL

Comment: Really, though. These type of code demand some old school P&P

Comment: I tried.. but I am getting confused. I got the output as cbacb

Comment: You need to show how the method is called in the first place.

Comment: It's not that complicated.  And we can't help you anyway, since you failed to provide a full example.

Comment: Damn, sorry! edited the qs. I call Mys(7) in main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `Mys(7)` you will get the specified output.

Here's how it works:

- `Mys(0)` always prints "a".
- `Mys(1)` always prints "b".
- `Mys(2)` always calls `Mys(1)` then `Mys(0)`, therefore always prints "ba".
- `Mys(3)` always prints "c".
- `Mys(4)` always calls `Mys(3)` then `Mys(2)`, therefore always prints "cba".
- `Mys(5)` always calls `Mys(4)` then `Mys(3)`, therefore always prints "cbac".
- `Mys(6)` always calls `Mys(5)` then `Mys(4)`, therefore always prints "cbaccba".
- `Mys(7)` always calls `Mys(6)` then `Mys(5)`, therefore always prints "cbaccbacbac".

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is your intention  that Your call  to `Mys(n-1)` will automatically call `Mys(n-2)` and hence give you multiple output for the *same number*.

If `n=6`, it will

1. Call `Mys(5)` which  will call `Mys(4)` and `Mys(3)`
2. and then call `Mys(4)` which will call `Mys(3)` and `Mys(2)`

`Mys(2)` will then call `Mys(1)` and `Mys(0)`